# It is possible to specify/reduce the onTap area of the items on a mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a `mapview`, with `itemizedoverlay`, like on Android developers example. But now I have a problem. When the user presses 1 or 2 cm out of the 32x32 image of the item on the map, the dialog of the item opens. I don't want that. I want to reduce the "press" area of the item to the 32x32 proportions of the image of the item on the map

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i remove the ontap area by clearing the ontap method

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ItemizedOverlay, and ended up using a normal Overlay instead. Then I needed to write my own method for measuring users tap on screen, and used the approach in this article:

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/03/19/tutorial-2-mapview-google-map-hit-testing-for-display-of-popup-windows/

If anyone has the solution to the ItemizedOverlay it would be great if they could share.

BR,
Vanja